# making custom placeholder in css or javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, placeholder

I want to style placeholder like this:

This is my **placholder**

where bolded text will be red and the rest will be black.

Thank you for your answers.

Comment: https://www.google.com/#q=style+placeholder

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind using javascript/jquery, here is an option for you: **[JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/jrulle/tpnnsL64/)**
*Essentially, you are setting up your input elements inside of DIVs with absolutely positioned placeholders below them. The javascript hides the placeholder text when the text field has focus and keeps it hidden if a value has been entered.* As you can see from the fiddle, the classes can be used for multiple inputs on the same page and the javascript handles the show/hide functions independantly without needing unique markup for each.

HTML:

```
<div class="myinput-div">
    <input class="myinput" type="text"/>
    <p class="myinput-placeholder">placeholder</p>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
p.myinput-placeholder {  
    position: absolute;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 4px;
    top: 0; left: 0; bottom: 0; right: 0;
    color: #e6e6e6;
    z-index: -1;
}
div.myinput-div {
    position: relative;
    width: 100px;
}
input.myinput {
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 10;
    background: none;
    border: 1px solid #c6c6c6;
    padding: 3px;
}
```

Javascript(jQuery):

```
$('.myinput').on("focus", function(){
     $(this).siblings('.myinput-placeholder').eq(0).hide();
});
$('.myinput').on("blur", function(){
     if($(this).val() == "") {
         $(this).siblings('.myinput-placeholder').eq(0).show();
     }
});
```

Answer (score -1):

```
*::-webkit-input-placeholder {
     //here is your code
}
*::-moz-placeholder {
    /* FF 4-18 */
 //here is your code
}
*:-ms-input-placeholder {
    /* IE 10+ */
 //here is your code
}
```

Comment: Didn't add explanation as to it will solve his answer or not.